# Running mice with a formula as a variable: instant evaluation instead of later evaluation?

Tags: r, evaluation, r-mice

The `R` package `mice`comes with following example:

```
library("mice")
imp <- mice(nhanes)
fit <- with(data=imp,exp=lm(bmi~hyp+chl))
```

I want a flexible call of `with()` like:

```
model_formula <- bmi~hyp+chl
fit <- with(data=imp,exp=lm(model_formula))
```

But this throws `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'bmi' not found`. I searched for similar problems. The closet problem I found was [Help understand the error in a function I defined in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498177/help-understand-the-error-in-a-function-i-defined-in-r).
My impression is, that writing `exp=lm(model_formula)` the expression `lm(model_formula)` is evaluted instantly, but when writing `exp = lm(bmi~hyp+chl)` it is not evaluated straight away - instead the eavluation will take place in the function `with.mice()`? And if so, how can I prevent instant evaluation?

Comment: I think this is likely a scoping issue, rather than time of evaluation, due to how with.mids is written. As an alternative , you could define the formula as a string , `model_formula <- "bmi~hyp+chl"` , and then define the formula within the with.mids scope `with(imp, lm(formula(model_formula)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @user20650 was the clue to the solution. It is needed to change the formula first to a character, which will be achieved by `format`, and made it then a formula again:

```
model_formula <- bmi~hyp+chl
fit <- with(data=imp,exp=lm(formula(format(model_formula))))
```

Comment: You know what aligns with your workflow, but it does seem suboptimal to define your model as a formula, convert it to a character, and then back to a formula. ps some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671172/how-to-convert-r-formula-to-text) show issue with using `format` in this way.

Comment: formula(format(...))) produces the following warning:
Using formula(x) is deprecated when x is a character vector of length > 1. Consider formula(paste(x, collapse = " ")) instead. This did the trick but it is very wordy: formula(paste(format(model_formula),collapse=' ')))